# Make Favorites default focus when starting Windows 8 Explorer

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer

I currently have Explorer pinned to my taskbar; when I click it it focuses on This PC.

When I hit `Win+e` a new explorer window pops up, also focused on This PC.

In both of those instances, I would like it to focus Favorites. After all, they're my favorites because I put things there that I'm working on currently.

Is there any way to manage this?

Comment: http://www.pcworld.com/article/239258/win_ex_default.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I've found a workaround, and I'd prefer a better answer, because my answer:

- will get you a duplicate icon on your task bar;
- will not work for the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> shortcut;

It is based on @Dave's comment.

1. Create a new shortcut somewhere. E.g. I created a "My Links" folder in My Documents, right-clicked, selected New Shortcut.
2. Make sure that the shortcut has an empty "Start in:" setting, and as a target:

   `%windir%\explorer.exe shell:::{323CA680-C24D-4099-B94D-446DD2D7249E}`
3. Drag this link to your task bar.

The good thing is that mentioned command will open a file explorer focused on "Favorites". I would've preferred to change the settings of the default "File Explorer" link, but when I tried to change the properties of that task bar icon as suggested in [the article mentioned by @Dave](http://www.pcworld.com/article/239258/win_ex_default.html) (and forums to which that post links) it wasn't possible: they were disabled.